# Get how many users who responded to a survey

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I need to know how many users who responded to a survey. But they can respond one or more times (in my case, two times max).

So I have two tables: `fs_users` and `fs_surveys`.

```
fs_users:
  ID  | Name
  1     David
  2     John

fs_surveys:
  ID  | ID_User | Selected_Answer
  1     1         A
  2     1         C
  3     2         A
```

If I count *visually* how many users who responded the survey, I can count `2` (David and John). By query, I can know who are this peoples that responded to. Like:

```
SELECT 
  fs_users.ID, 
  fs_users.Name
FROM fs_users

INNER JOIN fs_surveys
  ON fs_surveys.ID_User = fs_users.ID

GROUP BY 
  fs_users.ID
```

It basically will return the same of `fs_users` data represented above. So, until here I'm fine. The problem is that I need to `COUNT()` *how many users*, instead of, *who users*.

If I just change the `SELECT` to something like:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
...
```

I will receive this:

```
result:
  COUNT(*) | INSTEAD_OF
  3          2
```

So, how I can solve this problem? Bye!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID_User) FROM fs_surveys
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25762/1/0).

Comment: I think that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @eggyal Humm, or I've seen bad the sqlfiddle or you updated it :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM fs_users;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `COUNT(distinct columnName)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [COUNT(DISTINCT fs_users.ID)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) for counting unique values.